# "new String()" causes GC_CONCURRENT statements?

Tags: android

the Line

```
strPuffer = new String(buffer, 0, bytes, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

causes a lot of GC_CONCURRENT...

```
while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    strPuffer = new String(buffer, 0, bytes, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
                    curMsg.append(strPuffer);
                    int endIdx = curMsg.indexOf(end); 
                    if (endIdx != -1) { 
                        fullMessage = curMsg.substring(0, endIdx + end.length()-1); 
                        curMsg.delete(0, endIdx + end.length()); 
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, fullMessage)
                            .sendToTarget();}
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //
                    connectionLost();
                    break;
                }

            }
```

how can I prevent that?

Comment: isn't it a good sign that your garbage Collector is working fine? :)

Comment: If you're that adverse to GC messages you could always use a ByteBuffer & CharsetDecoder to do the same thing (in a few more *loc*) as `new String(..)`.

Comment: one Entry each second? ist this OK?

Comment: as long as you're not leaking memory you typically shouldn't worry. the GC in Android is functional enough to support your use.

Comment: @user1318171 as a rule of thumb: Never create a string using the `new`-operator. If you have to, that's always a bad sign. Since it seems that you're just reading Strings (line-by-line) from an input-stream, why not use a `StringBuilder` to construct the string and a `BufferedReader` for the buffer-implementation (considering you're not reading any binary data). Just thinking "The GC will do this" is bad and a sign of misunderstanding in the principle of garbage-collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a lot of objects in a loop. Seeing this message just means the garbage collector is doing its job by keeping your memory freed up. The GC cleans up objects in the heap which aren't referenced.